# Use of parenthesis in c

Tags: c, parentheses

What is the difference of the 2 following statements, regarding the use of parenthesis? (No pointers or so)

```
#define UART1_BAUD (460800)
#define UART2_BAUD 9600
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `()` should make no difference in a macro when it's just one literal or constant. However, you should for example do `#define FOO (BAR + BAZ)` instead `#define FOO BAR + BAZ` to avoid any nasty surprise due to operator precedence.

Comment: It is common that insecure rookie programmers like to put parenthesis around everything and its mother, because they are uncertain of how the language works. It's the same issue as insecure programmers writing `return (0);` from functions etc. The parenthesis is just clutter and adds absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that rookies tend to put parenthesis everywhere. However, for **C** `return()`, it's more for me an opinion based thing. With current C ANSI, the last `return(0);` is optional, but some old ones like me tend to keep it, and keep parenthesis. My reason : `return` is a construct that takes a parameter and _returns_ something, and it can be also a macro construct that will require parenthesis anyway, so i prefer to keep its parenthesis for consistency and readability (and yes i'm an old LISP fan). For the optional last `return 0;`, i keep it mainly for the 'don't surprise others'.

Comment: @Zilog80 `return` is a _jump statement_. It doesn't take parameters but optionally an expression. It is the _only_ jump statement taking an expression so what exactly are you trying to be consistent with? In case you are trying to be consistent with selection statements, I bet you _don't_ write for example your for loops like `for( int (i)=(0); ((i)<(n)); ((i)++) )`. Regarding return being optional, it is only optional in main(). Everywhere else you always need one, in case the function returns a value.

Comment: @Lundin I see your point, however as the `return` statement is part of functions and can take an optional expression, i'm uneasy to consider it on par with the `goto` statement. For the consistency point, it's mainly regarding the case of parametrized macros that handle the return operation, having _'return'_ parenthesized macros and un-parenthesized _return_ in the same source doesn't fit for me.

Comment: @Zilog80 It doesn't matter what you _feel_ that `return` should be, it is listed as a jump statement in the formal language syntax, C17 6.8.6, period. There's a lot of things "part of functions", like for example the function parameters. If you write your functions like `int f (int (x), int(y));` then I can see your point, otherwise not. Now if you have `return` inside function-like macros, then that's no longer just a style problem, but a highly fishy program design problem...

Comment: @Lundin Yes the `return` statement is a _jump statement_, but, regarding _style_, does that require it must be wrote in the same way as the `goto` statement ? For the macros case, macros pointer type casting for returns in dynamic library code doesn't fishy to me (FARPROC and void * : 5.3.1 Generic Pointers _"Any pointer to an object or incomplete type (but not to a function type) can be converted to type void * and back without change. Type void * is considered to be neither an object pointer nor a function pointer."_) ? Maybe i'm awful in design...

Comment: @Zilog80 I have no idea what you are on about, but yes generic function pointer types like Win API `FARPROC` is pretty bad design and converting between them and `void*` is undefined behavior. If you refer to some case like `#define UB_RETURN (x) return (FARPROC)some_void_pointer;` or the other way around, then yes that's horrible design relying on undefined behavior and non-standard extensions.

Comment: @Zilog80: I do not know what that “Generic Pointers” quote is from, but it is not the C standard, and `void *` is a pointer to an object type in C.

Comment: @Zilog80: If you have some “parameterized macros that handle the return operation” like `ERROR_RETURN(some, arguments);` or `FUNKY_RETURN(whatever);`, then the way you keep consistency is by using a macro `NORMAL_RETURN(value);` or `RETURN(value);`, not by writing `return (value);`. And then, inside all of those macros, you can have a plain `return value;`, as was intended by the laws of nature and all that is right and good in the world.

Comment: @Lundin Seems i've been unclear. I was referring to the case of C wrapper library code that deals with Windows API **or** libdl API, it is to avoid that kind of bad pointer casting for a code that should build on Windows like UNIX.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You got a point regarding consistency ^^.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference when the macros are used normally as operands in expressions.

Note however, there is a difference in

```
#define A 4 + 7
#define B (5 + 3)
```

if you use the macros as

```
int a = 6 * A; // 6 * 4 + 7 ==> 24 + 7
int b = 6 * B; // 6 * (5 + 3) ==> 6 * 8
```

As a rule of thumb: **use, and abuse, parenthesis in macros**.

When parenthesis immediately follow the macro name, it's a *function-like macro*

```
#define SQUARE(BAR) ((BAR) * (BAR)) // use and abuse parenthesis
```

Comment: Maybe you should describe macro expansion too (`#define FUNC(PARAM) PARAM + 7`) ?

Comment: “No difference whatsoever” is incorrect. `UART2_BAUD` could be used in situations with the concatenation operator `##` to form an identifier. `UART1_BAUD` cannot.

Comment: I think you are better off writing something like “There is no difference when the macros are used normally as operands in expressions” and avoiding details. Use with `##` is not the only difference. Another is `if UART1_BAUD` would be valid syntax whereas `if UART2_BAUD` would not. Another is `Foo(Bar UART1_BAUD)` would cause `Bar UART1_BAUD` to be macro-replaced after replacement of macro `Foo` if `Bar` were a function-like macro (because `Bar (460800)` forms a function-like macro invocation), but `Foo(Bar UART2_BAUD)` would not. (`Bar 9600` does not invoke the macro). There may be others.